# Summarizing leaf node values in a tree using SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a column containing a set of strings that represent leaf nodes in a tree, along with some statistics:

```
leafnodes count
--------- -----
/a/b      1
/a/c      3
/d/e/f    2
/d/e/c    5
```

How can I generate the set of non-leaf nodes with summarized statistics? It would be nice to summarize both the immediate children and also recursively summarize all descendents.

```
non-leafnodes    immediate-counts    recursive-counts
---              ----------------    ----------------
/a               4                   4
/d               0                   7
/d/e             7                   7
```

Generic SQL preferred, but Oracle-specific solutions are fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic SQL solution, except adding precalculated fields into table, for oracle you do use [Hierarchical queries](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2038) but then better to change structure anyway, as you will have to struggle with substrings